# Using Find() with inheritance in entity frameowrk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to find a User entity in my "Domain Entity" DB Set.
The User entity is derived from a base type called Domain Entity.

I want to use the following to find a user according to his ID

```
User userToDelte = db.DomainEntities.OfType<User>().Find(UserID);
```

But I get a compiler error :

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find'
>   accepting a first argument of type...

Why can't I use `Find()` after I have used `OfType<User>()` ?

P.S
It is important for me to get a strongly typed User entity because it has a navigation propertiy that include all of it's details in a separate table called "UserDetails" along with the user name and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method is declared in `DbSet` not `System.Linq.IQueryable`. Instead of that use the [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method of `DbContext` to create the `DbSet`.

```
User userToDelte = db.Set<User>().Find(UserID);
```